# I want to make a random number generator with custom link result

Tags: html, reactjs, web, embed

I want to create an option in my website which makes a random number between 1 - 2500. And after any number is selected i will redirect you to a custom link fro example: 30 redirect to https://30.com....
1323 redirect to https://1323.com... (I have a limited knowledge in coding )
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for generating a random number between two values, use

```
let randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2500) + 1)
```

you can then format this number into a link using an  tag on the element that will be redirecting the user with like so

```
let link = `https://${randInt}.com` // making the link
<a href={link}>Element</a> // adding link to the element that redirects the user
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: sorry, fixed it! @GreyMurav